# How to get data indexed by date from a panda

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am reading a stock daily data into a panda:

dpa = pd.read_csv(fname,parse_dates=['Date'])
print(dpa.head(5))

```
        Date   Open   High    Low  Close
0 2017-05-10  56.85  56.94  56.08  56.27
1 2017-05-11  56.13  56.38  55.80  56.23
2 2017-05-12  56.16  56.40  55.96  56.16
3 2017-05-15  56.07  56.76  56.01  56.70
4 2017-05-16  56.87  58.38  56.45  56.83
```

How can I use Date as the index and retrieve a column by specifying a date?

following didn't work:

```
 Close = dpa.Close['2017-05-12']

 Close = dpa['2017-05-12'].Close
```

I thought parse_dates = ['Date'] generates Date as index.

Comment: Either `dpa = dpa.set_index('Date')` or pass `index_col=0` or `index_col='Date'` while reading the csv. It will only parse the dates but will not set it as index if you don't specify the index.

Comment: From the document *A fast-path exists for iso8601-formatted dates.* not set index ...

Comment: Thank you - index_col='Date' while reading the csv file worked as expected.